# I'm working on a medical expert system project, the problem is my system is failing to pass the diagnosis to the browser

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Below is my *forms.py* code.

```py
class SymptomForm(forms.Form):
    symptoms = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['symptoms'].choices = self.get_symptoms_choices()

    def get_symptoms_choices(self):
        symptoms = Symptom.objects.order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True)
        return [(symptom, symptom) for symptom in symptoms]
```

Below is my model.

```py
from django.db import models

class Symptom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Below is my views code for the diagnosis function.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Symptom
from .forms import SymptomForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import pickle

@login_required
def diagnosis(request):
    with open('diagnosis/ml_model.sav', 'rb') as f:
        model = pickle.load(f)
    symptoms = Symptom.objects.order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True)
    form = SymptomForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SymptomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            selected_symptoms = form.cleaned_data.get('symptoms')
            feature_vector = [1 if symptom in selected_symptoms else 0 for symptom in symptoms]

            #make prediction
            diagnose = model.predict([feature_vector])[0]

            #Display result
            context = {'diagnose':diagnose, 'selected_symptoms':selected_symptoms}
            return render(request, 'pages/diagnosis.html', context)
        else:
            form = SymptomForm()
        form.fields['symptoms'].choices=[(symptom,symptom) for symptom in symptoms]
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'pages/diagnosis.html', context)
```

[image]
That's the screenshot for my diagnosis page, I want the user to select symptoms from the symptoms list. I'm able to select and display the selected symptoms (I used JavaScript for that) under the 'Selected Symptoms' heading. When I click the diagnose page the system is returning nothing, instead it act as if I just refreshed the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url mapping of your code.